# Exception silently ignored inside context manager decorated method

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, contextmanager

The following code appears not to raise. Is that a bug or have I not correctly understood the error handling in context managers?

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager

class Dataset:
    _getToRaise = False
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if self._getToRaise:
            print("It is supposed to raise here")
            raise ValueError
        return 0
    
    @contextmanager
    def getToRaise(self):
        try:
            self._getToRaise = True
            print('Entering context manager')
            yield
        finally:
            print('Exiting context manager')
            self._getToRaise = False
            return
    
d = Dataset()
with d.getToRaise():
    d[0]
```

Running the code in Python 3.8.17 returns:

```
Entering context manager
It is supposed to raise here
Exiting context manager
```

and no exception is raised...

Comment: Documentation of `contextmanager` says: "[...] the generator must reraise that exception. Otherwise the generator context manager will indicate to the with statement that the exception has been handled, and execution will resume with the statement immediately following the with statement."

Comment: That is highly counter-intuitive, particularly if the exception is unhandled and random.... Please make an answer and I am going to approve it as solved..

Comment: Fun fact: [ruff](https://beta.ruff.rs) has a rule that forbids `return` in a `finally` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `return` in the finally-block:

```
    @contextmanager
    def getToRaise(self):
        try:
            self._getToRaise = True
            print('Entering context manager')
            yield
        finally:
            print('Exiting context manager')
            self._getToRaise = False
            # return    <---- Comment out or remove
```

Comment: The problem OP is seeing has nothing to do with reraising the exception. Your last sentence is the actual fix to this.

Comment: @Wombatz Thank you. The documentation is a bit misleading (or just wrong?) here.

Comment: I dont believe it is misleading: "If an exception is trapped [...] the generator must reraise that exception". But OP did not trap it. So no need to reraise.

Comment: @Wombatz Ok, right. I was irritated that it was mentioned explicitly that an exception must be reraised after it was caught if it should be caught again. This is just the normal way so I thought it meant something else.

Comment: Yes that and the non-standard language of "capturing" an exception is a bit weird

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are not seeing the exception raised is because of the `return` statement inside the `finally` block in your `getToRaise context manager`. The `return` statement in the `finally` block will suppress any exception that occurred inside the context manager.

When an exception is raised inside the context manager, the `finally` block is still executed after the yield statement. In your case, the `finally` block contains the return statement, which means that the context manager will always return None, effectively suppressing any exceptions that occurred inside the context manager.

To fix this issue, you should remove the return statement from the finally block:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager



class Dataset:
        _getToRaise = False
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if self._getToRaise:
            print("It is supposed to raise here")
            raise ValueError
        return 0
    
    @contextmanager
    def getToRaise(self):
        try:
            self._getToRaise = True
            print('Entering context manager')
            yield
        finally:
            print('Exiting context manager')
            self._getToRaise = False

d = Dataset()
with d.getToRaise():
    d[0]
```

it should give output like this:

```
Entering context manager
It is supposed to raise here
Exiting context manager
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 20, in <module>
    d[0]
  File "example.py", line 8, in __getitem__
    raise ValueError
ValueError
```